# Python display for DNA transcription

Tags: python, python-2.7, bioinformatics

I wrote some Python code for a project to transcribe DNA into amino acids, however it does not seem to display correctly (read as: not at all [the amino acid part, at least]). Does anyone know where my flaws are? By the way, I am new to Python, so if the code looks a bit unruly, it's due to my lack of experience with conventions in Python. Thank you!

```
#DNA strand - does not need to be transcribed to RNA
dna = raw_input("What is the DNA strand that you need to be transcribed?")
#Start and Stop codons
start = "ATG"
stop1 = "TAA"
stop2 = "TAG"
stop3 = "TGA"
#Number of codons
divide = len(dna)
codon_number = divide / 3
total_codons = codon_number
#Now, to split the DNA!
codon_groups = []
multiplier = 1
if(total_codons > 0):
    codon_groups.append(dna[0:3])
    while (codon_number > 0):
        first = multiplier * 3
        second = first + 3
        up_next = dna[first:second]
        codon_groups.append(up_next)
        codon_number = codon_number - 1
        multiplier = multiplier + 1
print(codon_groups)
#The fun part is up next!
amino_acids = []
traverse = 0
up = 1
started = 0
stopped = 0
for codon in codon_groups:
    if(stopped == 0):
        acid = codon_groups[traverse:up]
        if (started == 0):
            if(acid == start):
                started = 1
                amino_acids.append("Start        Start - ATG")
                print(amino_acids)
        else:
            if(acid == "ATT" or acid == "ATC" or acid == "ATA"):
                amino_acids.append("Isoleucine  Ile I ATT ATC ATA")
            if(acid == "CTT" or acid == "CTC" or acid == "CTA" or acid ==    "CTG" or acid == "TTA" or acid == "TTG"):
                amino_acids.append("Leucine     Leu L CTT CTC CTA CTG TTA TTG")
            if(acid == "GTT" or acid == "GTC" or acid == "GTA" or acid == "GTG"):
                amino_acids.append("Valine      Val V GTT GTC GTA GTG")
            if(acid == "TTT" or acid == "TTC"):
                amino_acids.append("Phenylalanine Phe F TTT TTC")
            if(acid == "ATG"):
                amino_acids.append("Methionine  Met M ATG")
            if(acid == "TGT" or acid == "TGC"):
                amino_acids.append("Cysteine    Cys C TGT TGC")
            if(acid == "GCT" or acid == "GCC" or acid == "GCA" or acid == "GCG"):
                amino_acids.append("Alanine     Ala A GCT GCC GCA GCG")
            if(acid == "GGT" or acid == "GGA" or acid == "GGC" or acid == "GGG"):
                amino_acids.append("Glycine     Gly G GGT GGA GGC GGG")
            if(acid == "CCT" or acid == "CCA" or acid == "CCG" or acid == "CCC"):
                amino_acids.append("Proline     Pro P CCT CCA CCG CCC")
            if(acid == "ACT" or acid == "ACG" or acid == "ACC" or acid == "ACA"):
                amino_acids.append("Threonine   Thr T ACT ACG ACC ACA")
            if(acid == "TCT" or acid == "TCC" or acid == "TCA" or acid == "TCG" or acid == "AGT" or acid == "AGC"):
                amino_acids.append("Serine      Ser S TCT TCC TCA TCG AGT AGC")
            if(acid == "TAT" or acid == "TAC"):
                amino_acids.append("Tyrosine     Tyr Y TAT TAC")
            if(acid == "TGG"):
                amino_acids.append("Tryptophan   Trp W TGG")
            if(acid == "CAA" or acid == "CAG"):
                amino_acids.append("Glutamine    Glu Q CAA CAG")
            if(acid == "AAT" or acid == "AAC"):
                amino_acids.append("Asparagine   Asn N AAT AAC")
            if(acid == "CAT" or acid == "CAC"):
                amino_acids.append("Histidine   His H CAT CAC")
            if(acid == "GAA" or acid == "GAG"):
                amino_acids.append("GlutamicAcid Gln G GAA GAG")
            if(acid == "GAT" or acid == "GAC"):
                amino_acids.append("AsparticAcid Asn D GAT GAC")
            if(acid == "AAA" or acid == "AAG"):
                amino_acids.append("Lysine       Lys K AAA AAG")
            if(acid == "CGT" or acid == "CGC" or acid == "CGA" or acid == "CGG" or acid == "AGA" or acid == "AGG"):
                amino_acids.append("Arginine     Arg R CGT CGC CGA CGG AGA AGG")
            if(acid == stop1 or acid == stop2 or acid == stop3):
                amino_acids.append("Stop         Stop + TAA TAG TGA")
                stopped = 1
        traverse = traverse + 1
        up = up + 1

#Now it's display time
go = 0
gadget = 1
for amino in amino_acids:
    print(amino_acids[go:gadget])
    go = go + 1
    gadget = gadget + 1
```

Comment: I tried running your code and it asked "What is the DNA strand that you need to be transcribed?". What am I supposed to enter there? And what is the final output supposed to look like?

Comment: Which part isn't working? Breaking down the code and testing individual bits will make it easier to troubleshoot and fix the problem.

Comment: Add a strand of DNA, beginning with AUG and ending with one of the three "stop" codons previously listed. For example, I was using AUGTTTTAA to test the code.

Comment: The entire loop concerning the amino_acids list is causing the issue, but I'm not sure what it is since nothing from that section displays.

Comment: Ummm, isn't `start = ATG` yet your string starts `AUG`? That's a stab in the dark, it's a bit hard to follow.

Comment: I don't know anything about codons or whatever so I can't analyze the logic on that level. But glancing over the code, I think you may be misunderstanding how list indexing works. `some_list[a:b]` evaluates to a list, even if `a` and `b` are only one apart. For this reason, `if (acid == start):` will always fail, because `acid` is a list and `start` is a string. If you want to get a single item out of a list, use regular indexing: `some_list[a]`.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I typed that incorrectly when I replied here, but yes, it is ATG (and that is what I entered), but no, it doesn't work either way.

Comment: Thank you! I will see if it works if I change the indexing!

Comment: FWIW, you could convert codons to amino acids using a dictionary instead of that giant series of `if` statements.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps MattDMO's answer will be more convenient. However, I *think* I have fixed it with the most minor of changes to your existing code. I believe you misunderstand what `for codon in codon_groups` means; it's just iterating through the list of codons from your broken down string, assigning one item to the variable `codon` and providing it for you to use directly on each loop, before moving to the next codon in the list.

So:

```
for codon in codon_groups:
     print "codon", codon, "is made up of the following:"
     for nuc in codon:
         print(nuc)
     print "nucleotides"
```

Gives the output:

```
codon ATG is made up of the following:
A
T
G
nucleotides
codon TTT is made up of the following:
T
T
T
nucleotides
codon TAA is made up of the following:
T
A
A
nucleotides
```

Simply changing this one part will make it run:

```
for codon in codon_groups:
    print codon
    if(stopped == 0):
        acid = codon  # CHANGED HERE
        if (started == 0):
            if(acid == start):
                started = 1
                amino_acids.append("Start        Start - ATG")
                print(amino_acids)
```

There would be no need to actually make `acid = codon` and if the output is what you expected, then just remove the use of 'acid' or rename to `for acid in codon_group`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It works perfectly now, thank you.

Comment: @AmandaDoyle You are very welcome :) If you feel that this answer has closed this issue then please do consider marking it correct. Also I think you should take note of MattDMo's suggestion going for making this easier for you.

Answer (score 1):

You would be **much** better off using [Biopython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Biopython). You can read the [tutorial](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html) to get started. Here's an example of translating DNA into a protein sequence:

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC

dna_seq = Seq("ATGCTTCGGTCTGGGCCAGCCTCTGGGCCGTCCGTCCCCACTGGCCGGGCCATGCCGAGTCGCCGCGTCTAA", IUPAC.unambiguous_dna)
protein_seq = dna_seq.translate()
print(protein_seq)
```

gives

```
Seq('MLRSGPASGPSVPTGRAMPSRRV*', HasStopCodon(IUPACProtein(), '*'))
```

and

```
print(str(protein_seq))
```

gives the plain sequence:

```
'MLRSGPASGPSVPTGRAMPSRRV*'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually have to use Python for this project, but thanks for the suggestion (I kind of want to learn some languages that would be beneficial for biology in my own time). My code works now, though, but thank you for your help.

Comment: @AmandaDoyle this is Python. It's just a library that has been built to perform a specific task for you i.e. you don't have to write all the code yourself, someone else has written the logic. You should look up `pip install` to look at installing modules. This will make your life so much easier than reinventing the wheel :)